# Binding class from an array in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm starting with Ember.js and I'm feeling a bit lost. 
I have an object like this:

```
App.BRANDS = [
{
    brand:'Audi'
},{
    brand:'BMW'
},{
    brand:'Skoda'
}];
```

So what I'm trying is to display all the elements in that object with the {{#each}} component, show the text inside and bind the same text as a className. So I code this in the route:

```
App.InsuranceAutoSelectBrandRoute =  App.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.BRANDS;
  }
});
```

And this in the template:

```
<article>
  {{#each brand in model tagName='ul'}}
    <li class='item-space'>
      <span {{bind-attr class=':brand-auto classNameAuto'}}></span>
      {{brand.brand}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</article>
```

Then the issue is that the name of each brand, before I bind it as a class attr  I have to lowercase it...

```
App.InsuranceAutoSelectBrandController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  classNameAuto: function() {
    App.BRANDS.forEach(function(item, index){
      return item.brand.toLowerCase();
    });
  }.property()
});
```

If in the same point where I'm returning the value I make a log, it works, but the class attr is not showing.
What I'd like:

```
<article>
  <li class='item-space'>
    <span class='brand-auto audi'}}></span>
      Audi
  </li>
  <li class='item-space'>
    <span class='brand-auto bmw'}}></span>
    BMW
  </li>
  <li class='item-space'>
    <span class='brand-auto skoda'}}></span>
    Skoda
  </li>
</article>
```

Forgive me for my English level and thank you

Comment: Hello, let me start off by warning you that you are using deprecated syntax that has been removed in ember 2.0, and your templates contain broken code, what version of ember are you using and what guide are you following

Answer (score 1):

First, as @Kitler said, bind-attr is deprecated. If you are using 1.13.x or higher, you may just insert class as any other variable, `{{brand.brand}}`.

Second, your code is incorrect and will not work. The easiest way to do what you want is via helper. You need to create a helper, `lower-case` and use it in this way:

```
<article>
  <ul>
    {{#each model as |brand|}}
      <li class='item-space'>
        <span class='brand-auto {{lower-case brand.brand}}'>{{brand.brand}}</span>         
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</article>
```

How to create a helper you may learn from documentation (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/writing-helpers/). If you use ember-cli, following code should work:

```
//app/helpers/lower-case.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function (str) {
  return str.toLowerCase();
});
```